# How to fix content in div?

Tags: html, css

I am facing an issue while appending data in the Laravel blade file, the text-overflow the div.
I used **overflow-wrap: break-word;** property but it can break words that are so fishy.
How can I sort out without a sentence break?

> Html (with overflow-wrap: break-word):

[image]

```
 <div style="overflow-wrap: break-word;">
   <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Architecto&nbsp;quas&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;voluptas&nbsp;inventore,&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;repellat&nbsp;iure&nbsp;ad&nbsp;officia&nbsp;dicta,&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;neque?&nbsp;Voluptate&nbsp;ea&nbsp;quo&nbsp;deserunt&nbsp;nesciunt,&nbsp;quas&nbsp;inventore&nbsp;ducimus&nbsp;atque!</p>
   <ol>
      <li>
         <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Architecto&nbsp;quas&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;voluptas&nbsp;inventore,&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;repellat&nbsp;iure&nbsp;ad&nbsp;officia&nbsp;dicta,&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;neque?&nbsp;Voluptate&nbsp;ea&nbsp;quo&nbsp;deserunt&nbsp;nesciunt,&nbsp;quas&nbsp;inventore&nbsp;ducimus&nbsp;atque!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Architecto&nbsp;quas&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;voluptas&nbsp;inventore,&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;repellat&nbsp;iure&nbsp;ad&nbsp;officia&nbsp;dicta,&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;neque?&nbsp;Voluptate&nbsp;ea&nbsp;quo&nbsp;deserunt&nbsp;nesciunt,&nbsp;quas&nbsp;inventore&nbsp;ducimus&nbsp;atque!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Architecto&nbsp;quas&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;voluptas&nbsp;inventore,&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;repellat&nbsp;iure&nbsp;ad&nbsp;officia&nbsp;dicta,&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;neque?&nbsp;Voluptate&nbsp;ea&nbsp;quo&nbsp;deserunt&nbsp;nesciunt,&nbsp;quas&nbsp;inventore&nbsp;ducimus&nbsp;atque!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <p>Lorem&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;dolor&nbsp;sit&nbsp;amet&nbsp;consectetur&nbsp;adipisicing&nbsp;elit.&nbsp;Architecto&nbsp;quas&nbsp;sed,&nbsp;voluptas&nbsp;inventore,&nbsp;vitae&nbsp;repellat&nbsp;iure&nbsp;ad&nbsp;officia&nbsp;dicta,&nbsp;ipsum&nbsp;neque?&nbsp;Voluptate&nbsp;ea&nbsp;quo&nbsp;deserunt&nbsp;nesciunt,&nbsp;quas&nbsp;inventore&nbsp;ducimus&nbsp;atque!</p>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
```

> Html (without any CSS property):
> [image]

[image]

Comment: You use non-breakable spaces `&nbsp;`. Don't use them if you want proper breaks

Comment: @Deitsch if I don't use it, it can overflow the parent div.

Comment: Look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_word-wrap

Comment: Thanks, Brother its working @Deitsch

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
div p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```